# Is it possible to have a map that only allows value types based on the key?

Tags: java

I know this sounds a little crazy but here it is. I have an enum type that represents represents a bunch of different properties. Each could be just a string but it would be nice to enforce some kind of type safety. So basically check the type associated with each enum value and throw an exception if there is a mismatch. I guess it could be done with instance of but I am curious if there is another way to do this without instanceof. I know that may not be possible but I am curious.

Edit, I created a new example that I think illustrates what I am asking better:

```
public class CmisProperties {

    public enum CmisPropEnum{
        Name (PropertyIds.NAME, new String() ),
        CreatedBy (PropertyIds.CREATED_BY, new String()  ),
        CreationDate (PropertyIds.CREATION_DATE, new Date() ),
        LastModifiedBy (PropertyIds.LAST_MODIFIED_BY, new String() ),
        LastModificationDate (PropertyIds.LAST_MODIFICATION_DATE, new Date() ),
        ChangeToken (PropertyIds.CHANGE_TOKEN, new String()  );

            private String propId;

        CmisPropEnum ( String propId , Object templateObject ){
            this.propId = propId;
        }

        public <T> String getPropId(){
            return propId;
        }
    }

        private Map<CmisPropEnum, Object> propertyMap = new HashMap<CmisPropEnum, Object>();

    public Object getProperty(CmisPropEnum propEnum){
         return propertyMap.get(propEnum.getPropId());
    }

    public void setProperty( CmisPropEnum propEnum, Object value){
             propertyMap.put(propEnum, value);
    }
}
```

Later on I want this to happen:

```
CmisProperties props = new CmisProperties();
/* This causes a compile time exception */
props.setProperty(CmisPropEnum.CreationDate, "foobar" );
/* This I want to be ok, because the type matches that in the enum */
props.setProperty(CmisPropEnum.CreationDate, new Date() );
```

Comment: You can't get it to do a compile-time exception.  At least, I can't think of a way.  If you had your setProperty() method check value.getClass() vs. what is legal, before putting the value into the propertyMap, then you could get a runtime exception.

Answer (score 1):

Check out Josh Bloch's *Effective Java*, Item 29, where he describes a "typesafe heterogeneous container" that he calls Favorites.  The API is

```
public class Favorites {
   public <T> void putFavorite(Class<T> type, T instance);
   public <T> T getFavorite(Class<T> type);
}
```

I think it would fit your needs (probably change the name???).  You could call

```
favorite.putFavorite(Name.getClass(), "Fred");
favorite.putFavorite(ADate.getClass(), new Date(1234));
```

and later

```
Date date = favorite.getFavorite(ADate.getClass());
```

Comment: p.s.  Note that in this code you can only have **one** key-value pair of each type, since the class is the key.  Is that o.k.?

Comment: Note that, if `Name` and `ADate` are classes (as their capitalization would seem to imply), then the correct way to get their respective class objects would be as `Name.class` and `ADate.class`.  Otherwise, this looks like what the OP is asking for.

Comment: To answer user9493000, yes I was actually looking for a solution that would allow for multiple key(if by key you mean type) pairs. So, Sorry my example code was not clear. Name and ADate are just enums. I named them that so that it was clear what type I wanted them to be associated with. I guess I could have had ADate BDate CDate AString BString CString ... and so on. But thanks a bunch for your input.

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned by irreputable, you need classes to have variability based on types (i.e. generics). This is a corresponding generic version of your example:

```
public class Properties {

  public static class Property<E> {
    private Property(String name) { this.name = name; }
    private final String name;
    public String getName() { return name; }
  }
  public static final Property<String> NAME = new Property<String>("name");
  // ... other properties

  private Map<Property<?>, Object> propertyMap = 
    new HashMap<Property<?>, Object>();

  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") 
  public <E> E getProperty(Property<E> property){
    return (E) propertyMap.get(property);
  }
  public <E> void setProperty(Property<E> property, E value){
    propertyMap.put(property, value);
  } 

}
```

The usage is type-safe and checked at compile-time:

```
Properties p = new Properties();
p.setProperty(Properties.NAME, "a string"); // only strings allowed for NAME
String s = p.getProperty(Properties.NAME); // can only get strings for NAME
```

Answer (score 0):

Enums can't be generic, so we need a normal class

```
public class Prop<T>
{
    // some predefined props
    static public final Prop<String> NAME = new Prop<>("Name", String.class);
    ...

    public Prop(String name, Class<T> type) // it's ok, anyone can create new kind of Prop
    {...}

    Class<T> getClassT() {...}

}
```

then set/get property methods can have stronger static type checking:

```
private Map< Prop,Object > propMap = new HashMap<>();

public <T> void setProperty(Prop<T> key, T value){
    propMap.put(key, value);
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public <T> T getProperty(Prop<T> key)
{
    return (T)propMap.get(key);
}
```

so that this won't compile

```
setProperty(Prop.NAME, new Integer(1)); // fail

int x = getProperty(Prop.NAME); //fail
```

note that, each entry in the `propMap` has a key `Prop<X>` and value `X` for some `X`, and `X` can be different from entry to entry. We cannot really express that constraint on `Map` in Java; but the constraint is indeed enforced by app logic (i.e. `setProperty()` only inserts such entries)

In `getProperty` we must suppress unchecked warning. It is justified, since we know the value for the key must be of type `T`, due to previously mentioned constraint. One trick to avoid explicitly suppressing the warning is by `Class.cast()`

```
public <T> T getProperty(Prop<T> key)
{
    return key.getClassT().cast( propMap.get(key) );
}
```

but it's only a trick since essentially we moved @SupressWarnings to `Class.cast()`. This is a worse version in performance and in semantic clarity.

Comment: If you aren't using the `Class` object, it serves no purpose. You can get the same static typing with generics alone.